# scanf optional matching

Tags: c, scanf

So I have to get scanf to read in a few strings that are separated by spaces. However, I don't know beforehand how many strings I need to read it it can be anywhere from 1 to 5, but I can't seem to get scanf to stop trying to read after hitting enter in the input. I have tried doing the naive `%s %s %s %s %s` but as you can imagine after hitting enter after say just 1 or 2 words it still expects to read more in and then I also tried to do `%s%*[^\n]%s%*[^\n]%s%*[\n]%s%*[\n]%s%*[^\n]` so that it would try to stop after a new line character but that didn't work either.

So what is the best way to get scanf to be able to have some optional input sections.

Thanks.

Edit: I know about strtok and fgets I was just looking to see if there was a way to do this with scanf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `fgets` to read one line and then `strotk` / `sscanf` to parse it ? Then you'll be able to decide how many strings the user has entered.

Comment: Well that is what I am likely going to do I was just wondering if there was a way to do it like this.

Comment: @legion Well there *might* be a way, but using `scanf` is inherently unreliable. You don't have much control on what the user enters. On the other hand when you use `fgets` you have all the string in a buffer, you have complete freedom to parse it as you see fit, without `scanf` standing in the way.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` doesn't enforce reading the whole format string, it aborts once it gets invalid input or no input is left.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/:

> On success, the function returns the number of items successfully
>   read. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer,
>   even zero, if a matching failure happens.

The following code tells you how many arguments were read during `scanf`:

```
char s1[10], s2[11], s3[11], s4[11], s5[11];
int read = scanf("%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s", s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
printf("Read %d strings", read);
```

If you enter `aaa bbb ccc` and hit enter, it prints 3, for `aaa bbb ccc ddd` it prints 4, etc.